# How to connect my c++ code with forms in visual studio c++?

Tags: c++, forms, button, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I am really new in this thing and I am making baby steps, so it might be a silly question.
I made a .cpp file that I was running in "Dev C++" program. 
I need to visualize some of the results of my program(charts etc), so I need to somehow connect my code with the form I made in Visual Studio. Results will be changing every time, so I can't just write them by hand.
My idea is to have a button and when the user click on it, it will run my c++ program and when the results are ready, they will be performed on a chart.

My code is like this for now and its running but I didn't finish it yet, cause my main problem now is to find a way to run this program from visual studio and somehow connect it with a button.

Should I call an eventHandler or sth? Should I write sth on my .cpp file so it can somehow connect with the form?

using namespace std;

/* Extract all integers from string */
void extractIntegerWords(string str) 
{ 
    stringstream ss;

```
/* Storing the whole string into string stream */
ss << str; 

/* Running loop till the end of the stream */
string temp; 
int found; 
while (!ss.eof()) { 

    /* extracting word by word from stream */
    ss >> temp; 

    /* Checking the given word is integer or not */
    if (stringstream(temp) >> found) 
        cout << found << " "; 

    /* To save from space at the end of string */
    temp = ""; 
}
```

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i=0,count_elements=0,a=0;

```
string line;
string keyword[2];


ifstream readyfile("file.map");
ofstream newfile("search_list.txt");



//Give the keywords
keyword[0] = {"Module                                            ro code "};
keyword[1] = {"Grand Total:"};


cout<< endl;



while(getline(readyfile,line))
{
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if (line.find(keyword[i]) != std::string::npos)
        {
            count_elements++;


            int n = line.length(); 
            line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\''), line.end());
            extractIntegerWords(line);
            newfile<<line<<endl;
        }           
    }
}   

cout<<"Process has been completed!"<<endl;
cout<<"There have been "<<count_elements<<" elements found and written on the file"<<endl;

readyfile.close();
newfile.close();


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}